# Django: Relational view in template [many-to-one relationship]

Tags: django, django-models, orm, jinja2, python-3.7

I have a many-to-one relationship in my models. And I want to view the data of my child table in `html table` related to the parent table. Here's my models.py:

```
class DataCollection(models.Model):
    default_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class NameHistory(models.Model):
    old_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collection_data = models.ForeignKey(DataCollection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And here's my views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):

foo = ( DataCollection.objects
                  .annotate(
                   first_old_name=Window(
                   expression=FirstValue('namehistory__old_name'),
                   partition_by=[F('id'), ],
                   order_by=F('namehistory__id').desc()
                   )
                  )
                 .values_list('first_old_name', flat=True)
                .distinct()
            )
context = {
    'sample': foo,
    'dashboard': DataCollection.objects.all(),
    'title':'Dashboard'
}

return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_form.html', context)
```

My problem is, how can I view the data of this key `sample` in the template which is related to `id` of `DataCollection` table.

Here's a sample data in my models, `DataCollection`:

[image]

Here's a sample data for `NameHistory`:

[image]

So in my `html table` it should be something like this:

[image]

I tried this kind of code but I don't know why is it always returning the `No Name`:

```
<tbody>
{% for data in dashboard %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ data.default_name }}</td>
    {% for item in sample.namehistory_set.all %}
        <td>{{ item.old_name }}</td>
    {% empty %}
        <td> No Name </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You should use your annotated queryset for your dashboard/table as it will have the old name annotated on each object

```
foo = DataCollection.objects.annotate(
    first_old_name=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('namehistory__old_name'),
        partition_by=[F('id'), ],
        order_by=F('namehistory__id').desc()
    )
)
context = {
    'dashboard': foo,
    'title':'Dashboard'
}
```

Then in your template

```
<tbody>
{% for data in dashboard %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ data.default_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.first_old_name:default"No Name" }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I got an error, `Could not parse the remainder: ':default"No Name"' from 'data.first_old_name:default"No Name"'`

Comment: I tried to erase the ` default"No Name" ` . . then I got it. .